# Laravel Function called by Route returning '500' error. DB data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```js
   

 public function saveUserToGroup(Request $request, $username){

            if (!$this->secure($username)) return redirect('/404');

            $member = new UserHobby();

            $person = $request->input('person');
            $group = $this->group;

            $member->user_id = $person->id;
            $member->hobby_id = $group->id;

            if ($member->save()) {

                $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Your friend has been added to the group!');

            }else{
                $request->session()->flash('alert-danger', 'Something went wrong!');
            }

            return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'Success']);

        }
```

```css
     <form action="/social/{username}/save/group" method="POST">
      @csrf
     <table id="modal-table">
       @foreach($user_list->get() as $f)
          <tr>
             <td>
                    <div class="image">
                        @if($f->follower->avatar_location)
                           <img src="{{asset('storage/'.$f->follower->avatar_location)}}" class="img-circle" style="max-height:50px;" />                                     
                        @else                                    
                           <img src="{{url('/')}}/assets/media/icons/socialbuttons/user.png" class="img-circle" style="max-height:50px;"/>                                  
                        @endif
                   </div>
                   <div class="detail">
                        @if($f->follower->verified == 1)
                           {{ $f->follower->name }}<img id="verified_img_sm_mess_list" src="{{url('/')}}/assets/media/icons/socialbuttons/octagonal_star.png" alt="Recensioni">
                        @else
                           <h3>{{ $f->follower->name }}</h3>
                        @endif  
                        <small id="mess_list_uname">{{ '@'.$f->follower->username }}</small>
                   </div> 
                  <button type="submit" name="person" value="person" class="btn-link">Go</button> 
               </td>
             </tr>
           @endforeach
         </table>
        </form>
```

```html
     Route::post('/social/{username}/save/group', [GroupController::class, 'saveUserToGroup'])->name('socialprofile.save.user.group');
```

Hey guys, I'm new to all this, and not sure if I'm calling the route incorrectly or wrong application of my controller function. Obviously I'm trying to add a user from a list into a group. Please Help! I've been a little lost with this and looking for some help to understand where my errors are. Many thanks!

EDIT**
now log reading..
"'hobby_id' cannot be null"..

I have tried to change the variable to take the group id. and that reads error "trying to get id of non-object"

but am I not assigning hobby_id as the group_id?

The problem is that I want to add into 'hobby_id' the 'id' of the current group which this function is being called.

Comment: You're using `<a href...`, so the route should be `get`, not `post`. (Do you have `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file? Feels like "_whoops something went wrong_" should have a more detailed explanation of what went wrong) You can also take a look at `storage/logs/laravel.log` to get more details

Comment: Hi, yes I always check the log first, but it doesn't return an error. And following your advice I changed the href.. to a form, but on execution now returns a 419 'page expired' I'll update my code and thanks for you help!

Comment: Please share more details by editing your question - what's the problem with the given code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: `action="/social/{username}/save/group"` is not correct blade syntax, it should be something like `action="/social/{{$username}}/save/group"` Better yet, use the route name and add the parameter as described in [Generating URLs To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)